# What if there are two paths of least time?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, variational-principle

I’m reading Fermat’s principle of least time from the Feynman lectures. And the following question popped.

Suppose we have a medium whose the refractive index is a (continuous) function of the position. Then consider two points $A$ and $B$ in the medium.

**Question 1:** Can the refractive index be such a function of position that we have in fact *two* paths of “stationary” time (as I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle), it need not be least) form $A$ to $B$? (The time taken need not be the same for both the paths, but these paths make their corresponding times local extrema.)

**Question 2:** If such a refractive index medium ceases to exist, why so? If not, which path will the light go?

Comment: Interesting question. Sounds like a degenerate ground state, so my guess would be that both paths have equal probability "highest probability".

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298013/2451 and links therein.