# Why is the action guranteed to have unique extrema in classical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

Reading any classical mechanics book which introduces the Lagrangian formalism of mechanics, a one particle system is introduced to show that we obtain the euler-lagrange equations from Newton's second law when we introduce the lagrangian function. Then we proceed to generalize to Hamilton's principle but I have a few questions about this generalization.

- It was said in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3928/multiple-classical-paths-from-hamiltons-principle) answer that, in classical mechanics a particle takes a definite path and it happens to be the path which makes the action stationary. But, how do we guarantee, mathematically, that the functional will have only one function that makes it stationary? How do we guarantee that there wouldn't be multiple extrema? (I know physically there has to be only one solution but I do not see how that is guaranteed in the derivation.
- [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/115208/several-stationary-points-of-the-action-functional) answer suggests that there in QFT some functionals have multiple extrema, but since I have not taken QFT yet it would be nice if someone can give a gentle introduction as to why this is the case.

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203493/when-why-does-the-principle-of-least-action-plus-boundary-conditions-not-uniquel) answer, which was suggested to answer my question, does not answer my q as it does not motivate why for most classical systems we get only one extrema, my question is why was this guranteed and if not what was the factor which led to only one extrema?

Also it was suggested that given a set of initial conditions you get a unique solution but I am asking how do we know we get a unique "family" of solutions if you will

- example : sol $ y(t) = a t + c $ is a family of solutions for different a and c (initial conditions)
- My question is how do we know we wont get a linear and an exponential family of solutions to make the action stationary? how do we know we do not get multiple solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721769/2451

Comment: Hi realanswers. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Hi @Qmechanic Please stop closing all my posts thinking that your previous answers have answered my question because they have not. This is very discouraging and just abuse of power.