# How do you determine the Lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

1. I have always been puzzled by how do you arrive at Lagrangians?
2. That is, how do you know that the functional you need to get Newton's equations is 
   $$L  =  T-V(x)~?$$
3. Do you derive the Lagrangian first somehow or do you just guess the one which would satisfy the action to give equation's of motion? (because then you would need to know the equations of motion first.)
4. Also, is the Lagrangian always equivalent to something resembling $T-V$, or there are other ways to determine it?
5. More generally, *is the action known before you know the equations of motion, or vice versa*?
6. What I really wish to know is, was the Einstein Hilbert action discovered before field equations were? If so, *how*?
7. *My major doubt is how do you come across the Lagrangian if you don't know the equations of motion, and you can't guess $L$ then*?

Comment: In general, Lagrangian is found by educated guess based on a few principles: Lorentz invariance, gauge invariance, etc and experimental facts: parity non-conservation etc

Comment: But do you already need to know the equations of motion?

Comment: Adding to user26143's answer: Landau's Mechanics book, first chapter, have a nice derivation for the $T-V$ form of the Lagrangian for classical mechanical conservative systems, in general it can resemble that, but it has no obligation to it. In general you must combine symmetries that you believe that your system have with the fact that the Lagrangian should be a invariant to the action of the symmetry groups.

Comment: @GRrocks I don't think it's always necessary to know equation of motion first. Anyway equation of motion from least action principle is only a classical limit of quantum physics.

Comment: Usually, you use the Lagrangian to \textbf{find} the equations of motion, not the other way around

Comment: Several questions shown in the "Related" sidebar are equivalent (such as http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/), though none are phrased quite this way. It is worth noting that Lagrange developed his method *before* Hamilton stated his principle. As @user23873 notes, Landau shows how to do it, and so does Goldstein.

Comment: Is this in the context of classical mechanics? It's easy to proof that the Lagrangian you give is equivalent to Newton's equations (under certain conditions).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5648/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @user23873 In Landau's book the $-V$ term isn't justified in any way, just "appears to work".

Comment: Also interesting are the two papers by Wess, Zumino, Coleman on the 'Structure of Phenomenological Lagrangians'. @JamalS, you recently read these, didn't you? Is there anything interesting/insightful in them? Of course, this is beyond the level of the original question, but I think it's of much interest regardless.

Comment: "(My major doubt is how do you come across the Lagrangian if you don't know the equations of motion, and you can't guess L then)" That's why Joseph-Louis Lagrange was not the one who came up with the correct laws of electromagnetism.

Comment: @Ruslan, He justifies that one must have $T = \sum T_i$ if uses cartesian $\mathbb{R}^3$ for generalized coordinates and have free particles. For the $-V$ part, he impose restrictions on it's shape, through Galilean invariance, it's true that, from there on, it 'just works'

Comment: @GRrocks: There are a number of other questions - such as how can we add (subtract) the future (potential energy) to the present (kinetic energy) - but the biggest question of all is: **How come Lagrangian is non-zero (or 2T) for one field only (like gravity)?**

Comment: The first sentence is not a question, but there's a question mark on it. The rest of the post is literally an enumerated list of *six questions*. Please limit posts to one specific question.

Comment: @user26143: You are aware that Lagrangian mechanics works for things other than fundamental relativistic quantum fields, right? How do I use Lorentz invariance, gauge invariance, and parity non-conservation to get the Lagrangian of a ball rolling down a hill?

Comment: @DanielSank For this particular case (a ball rolling down a hill), I can guess from equation of motion to arrive at L=T-V. Since op is concerned at the situation when equation of motion is not known, I assume other consideration (symmetry etc) will be needed

Answer (score -1):

Not guessing at all. The action principle was discovered *after* Lagrange's equations of motion. So all you need to do is to arrive on it, from Newton's Laws. We know Newton's Laws in Cartesian coordinates. All we need to do them, is to convert it to generalized coordinates. So, let the definition of a generalized coordinate:
$$
q_k = q_k(x_i),\quad\quad
\dot q_k = \sum_i\frac{\partial q_k}{\partial x_i}\dot x_i\quad\quad
\delta x_i = \sum_k\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \delta q_k
$$

Notice that for a kinetic energy of a single particle $K$:
$$
K = \frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2  \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot x} = m\dot x = p
$$

This also works with angular momentum when coordinate is theta. Hence, let's define a generalize momentum this way:
$$
p_k = \frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q} =
\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot q}\sum_i\frac{1}{2}m\dot x_i^2 = 
\sum_i m\dot x_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial\dot q_k}
$$

This works in Cartesian coordinates, and polar coordinates, as giving linear and angular momentum. So, sounds a good definition. Now, let's define our generalized force $Q_k$ as the work done by a small displacement: 
$$\delta W = \sum_k Q_k\delta q_k = \sum_i F_i\delta x_i = 
\sum_i F_i\sum_k\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \delta q_k\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
Q_k = \sum_i F_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k}
$$

However, we know the potential energy and force are related:
$$
F_i = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
Q_k = -\sum_i \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k}
= -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_k}
$$

The derivative of momentum:
$$
\frac{dp_k}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\sum_i m\dot x_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial\dot q_k} = 
\sum_i\left(m\ddot x_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} + m\dot x_i\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k}\right)
$$

This can be reorganized only in terms of generalized coordinates:
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_k} = \sum_im\dot x_i\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{dp_k}{dt} = Q_k + \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_k}
$$
$$
Q_k = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_k}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_k}
$$

Now, since:
$$
Q_k = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_k}\quad\mbox{ and }\quad
\frac{\partial V}{\partial \dot q_k} = 0
$$

We can then write Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \dot q_k} - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_k} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_k}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_k}
$$

If we set $L = T - V$, we have:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_k} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_k} = 0
$$

Since this is a typical equation of functional minimization, from here we can derive action principle, and so on. As you can see, there were no guesses.

Comment: The OP was asking how we get a particular Lagrangian for some system. not the EL equation.