# Non-equilibrium Green functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, non-equilibrium

How do we use [non-equilibrium Green's functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=non+equilibrium+qft) (NEGF) or the [Keldysh formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keldysh_formalism) in the theory of quantum transport? Please take a simple example like the Hopping model with a non-equilibrium perturbation that couples two lattice sites for example, with increased hopping strength between those two particular lattice sites and explain in that context. Show with this simple example how we use the NEGF or the Keldysh formalism.

Comment: There is a lot of literature on this subject, see this [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/good-reading-on-the-keldysh-formalism) for reading lists. I would give you a worked example, but I'm learning this stuff myself at the moment! I would add to that list a new book [by Stefanucci and van Leeuwen](http://www.amazon.com/Nonequilibrium-Many-Body-Theory-Quantum-Systems/dp/0521766176) which just arrived in the mail today. If you have a decent library nearby it might be worth a shot...

Comment: @MichaelBrown Thanks- the reading list is useful. Looking forward to the worked example.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out that Lecture 1 in the lecture entitled
"Field Theoretical Methods for Non-equilibrium Transport Phenomena"
in the following link:
http://tfp1.physik.uni-freiburg.de/eu_www/Miraflores/
contains exactly the solution to the simple example (and more!) 
that you want to know.