# Textbooks for non-equilibrium quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, non-equilibrium

What are good textbooks for non-equilibrium quantum field theory? Please answer by naming quality books and a short description and review about each one that you have personally read or benefited from.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13997/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Found some interesting sources in there.