# Reference request for semiclassical approximations for Schwinger-Keldysh path integrals

Tags: resource-recommendations, path-integral, non-equilibrium, semiclassical, instantons

Can some one provide some resources for understanding semi-classical approximations for Schwinger-Keldysh path integrals. Is there any discussion about instanton (and multi-instanton) (for even single degree of freedom case would help) contributions to these path integrals in literature?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13997/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

A recent preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.05746 presents the construction of the Schwinger-Keldysh technique for systems with instantons (for the case of quantum mechanics with one degree of freedom).

Comment: Please note that if you are the author of the preprint in question, physics.SE policy requires you to clearly disclose that information - it's okay to cite yourself, but it should be made *clear* that you're citing yourself.