# Real-time Green Function in finite temperature

Tags: many-body, greens-functions

As in standard many-body textbook (at least in my class), we use real-time green function when temperatures is zero, and we use imaginary-time green function when the temperature is finite.

My question is: Is this just a convenient definition or is there some other reasons that we have to use different green functions?

To be more specific, what I mean by “convenient” is that, when the temperature is finite, we have to compute the partition function to get the expectation value, but the evolution operator $exp [-i H t]$ can not be combined with the partition function factor $exp[- \beta H]$ so we can not conveniently compute the result. Is this $the \, reason$ ?

Comment: Relevant : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/good-reading-on-the-keldysh-formalism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a matter of convenience. However, as I noted in the answer to your other question, non-equilibrium statistical mechanics makes use of the Green's functions with a time-contour that has both real and imaginary time parts. It is a somewhat advanced topic, however, there is rich literature on the subject:  Kadanoff & Baym's book, the book by Jauho, the [review by Rammer and Smith](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.58.323), and the [path integral formulation here](http://www.capri-school.eu/capri09/lectures/Kamenev_Capri09.pdf).