# Generalised Gell-Mann and Low theorem for explicitly time-dependent hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-field-theory, time, hamiltonian, vacuum

Is there a generalisation of the [Gell-Mann and Low theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem) that applies to the case of explicitly time-dependent hamiltonians? (Not on the original proof which is for $H=H_{0}+e^{-\epsilon|t|}V$, but rather for $H(t)=H_{0}+e^{-\epsilon|t|}V(t)$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Hamiltonian is time-dependent, then the system will not necessarily remain in the ground state, which forfeits the very statement of the Gell-Mann and Low theorem.

The standard way to bypass this problem is Keldysh formalism, where one evolves the system from $t=-\infty$ to the current moment and then back, so that averaging is still done in respect to the ground state: see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/538545/247642) for references.