# Question regarding the motivation behind finding Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

The Lagrangian method uses the Kinetic Energy and Potential Energy to give us the equation of motion, that's well and good.

But it seems too random to define a quantity called $L$ (action).

The expression for $L$ is $T-V$ (T- Kinetic Energy; V - Potential Energy ).

The major constraint is that $L$ must be minimized, why is that?

Why should the difference of kinetic energy and potential energy of a system be minimized. Is there any way to make sense of this?

Comment: Perhaps this video can clear some things up: https://youtu.be/Q_CQDSlmboA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Motivation for form of Lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86008/)

Comment: In the following answer (written by me, oct. 2021) the Lagrangian $L$ is demonstrated visually; the diagrams are animated GIFs. the frames of the animated GIFs show the process of sweeping out variation. That answer presents a [derivation of the Lagrangian L=T-V from first principles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670705/17198)

Comment: @Tachyon I notice you linked to the PBS Space Time youtube channel. There are multiple errors in that video, each severe enough to invalidate the narrative. The biggest error: Matt O'Dowd, the writer/presenter, asserts that according to GR motion along a geodesic is (among all other paths) the path of least proper time. For emphasis Matt prepared an image with that text. I took a screenshot: '[Principle of Least Proper Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpV0J.jpg). So it's not just a slip: Matt O'Dowd really believes that.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451 and links therein.