# Can't understand the principle of least action

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, optics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I tried many hours to understand the [principle of least action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), and those hours become days... and I still didn't understand that principle/ and how it relates to Newtonian mechanics?

Could someone please explain it to me easily?

Comment: for example if I have in *énoncé*, light travel between point $a$ and point $b$ in time $s$, we should formulate the equation of motion where the path is the shortest such that it takes $s$ time to travel from point $a$ and point $b$ by that time? Also how does this relate to Newtonian mechanics and how is it better?

Comment: ...what don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand what it means... why it is useful... :(

Comment: It gives you the equations of motion of whatever theory you use it for.

Comment: But how? How does it give you that... I wanna want an intuitive way of thinking about it

Comment: The 'intuition' = minimize the action. There really is no simpler way of stating it. Many find Lagrangian mechanics unsatisfying at first.

Comment: I should add that it is really the principle of stationary action (not just *least*).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the Principle of Least Action?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/)

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence Danu

Comment: No Danu I read the question why the principle of least action? but it does not help at all!

Comment: You should formulate your question more clearly then. What is there that remains unclear to you?

Comment: for example if i have *énoncé*, light travel between point a and point b in time s, we should formulate the equation of motion where the path is the shortest such that it takes s time to travel from point a and point b by that time? Also how does this relate to newtonian mechanics and how is it better?

Comment: This question may already have an answer here:

    Why the Principle of Least Action? 6 answers

NOOOOOOOOOO!!!!

Comment: Also in principle of least action there are the words: 'least' and 'action' which i don't understand correctly m... maybe

Comment: Instead of least it should be extremum, you should read about this in a classical mechanics book. It could be a maximum action.

Comment: The relation with Newtonian Mechanics is that if the action is $\int Ldt$ where $L=T-V$ you get the same equations of motion Newton's laws give you.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.
Let's consider the case of a free particle in a force field given by a potential $U$. If $$L=T-U,$$ 
then the Newton's equations of motion $$\dot {\mathbf p}=-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \mathbf r}$$ 
are equivalent to Lagrange's equation in Cartesian coordinates:
$$\dot {\mathbf p} = \frac{\partial L}{{\partial \mathbf  q}},$$
with $\mathbf q = \mathbf r$.

The principle of least action states that motion $\gamma$ beetween two points of the generalized configurations space,  $(\mathbf r _1,t_1)$ and $(\mathbf r _2,t_2)$, is **the** one that makes the action $S(\gamma)=\int _{t_1}^{t_2} L(\gamma (t),\dot\gamma(t)) \text d t$ stationary, meaning that the linear part (the so called differential) of the variation $$\delta S(\gamma,h)=S(\gamma+h)-S(\gamma)$$
is zero in $\gamma $.

This two things are linked by the fact that (for a sufficiently nice $L$) this condition is equivalent to the Lagrange's equation above mentioned.

An interesting feature of this principle is that it doesn't depend on the system of coordinates chosen, which gives a lot of freedom in choosing the more appropriate set of coordinates for the problems.

To give an application, suppose that $\mathbf r=(x,y)$ are the cartesian coordinates of a point in the plane and let $\pi= (r,\theta):\mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R ^2$ be the polar coordinates. Suppose that $$\mathbf r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$$
is a solution of the equations of motion. Then we can show easily that $$\mathbf q(t)=\pi (\mathbf r(t)),$$ which is the projection onto the polar plane of this solution, solves the equations of motion $$\dfrac{\text d }{\text d t} \dfrac{\partial \tilde L}{\partial \dot {\mathbf q}}=\dfrac{ \partial \tilde L}{\partial \mathbf q},$$
that is, Lagrange's equation are still valid in the new system of coordinates, with a new Lagrangian given by $$\tilde L(\mathbf q ,\dot {\mathbf q})=L(\mathbf r,\dot {\mathbf r}).$$ In fact by definition of $\tilde L$, we have $$\int _{t_1} ^{t_2} \tilde L(\mathbf q (t),\dot { \mathbf q}(t)) \text d t=\int _{t_1} ^{t_2} L(\mathbf r (t),\dot { \mathbf r}(t) )\text d t.$$

Since $\mathbf r$ satisfies Lagrange's equations, it minimizes the action associated to $L$. So $\mathbf q$ minimizes the action associated to $\tilde L.$ So $\mathbf q$ satisfies Lagrange's equations with the new Lagrangian.