# Lagrangian Systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Given a manifold $M$, Arnold's "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" defines a Lagrangian system as a pair $(M,L)$ where $L$ is some smooth function on the tangent bundle $TM$. The function $L$ is called the Lagrangian. In the case when $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and a particle in $M$ is moving under some conservative force field, taking the Lagrangian to be the kinetic minus the potential energy we recover Newton's second law.

I know that one of the main advantages to the Euler-Lagrange equations over Newtons is the way in which they simplify constrained systems. I know another is the coordinate independence of the equations. However, in all applications I've seen the manifold is always Riemannian and the Lagrangian is always $K-U$.

My questions are:

1. Why do we have this abstract definition of a Lagrangian system and of an abstract Lagrangian?
2. What are some of the cases in which $L$ is not $K-U$ that gives interesting results?
3. Or cases in which the manifold is not Riemannian?

Comment: Subquestion 2 is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451 . Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9/2451 ,  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Suggestions to the question (v2): 1. Remove duplicate questions 2. Ask only one question per post. 3. Besides Riemannian manifolds mention [Lorentzian manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) to include relativistic theories.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're saying that I should remove question 2, and only ask question 3?