Deeper explanation for Principle of Stationary Action
The Principle of Stationary Action (sometimes called Principle of Least Action and other names) is successfully applied in a wide variety of fields in physics. It can often can be be used to derive basic equations of the respective field. For example, in classical mechanics, electrodynamics, thermodynamics, general relativity, quantum mechanics, and quantum field theory. Is there any deeper explanation for the validity of this miraculous principle in such a diverse number of areas in physics?

It is explained by path integration.

In a 2021 answer I discussed the case of Hamilton's stationary action Analogous case: Fermat's stationary time It seems plausible that the reasoning generalizes to other instances of application of stationary action.

In classical mechanics, the action is stationary along the path where $F=ma$ holds at each point.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9/2451 and links therein.

@ Qmechanic Thank for pointing out these two related questions on PSE! I have looked at them and the answers and will refer to them in my edited question

@ naturallyInconsistent Thank you for your interesting hint!  I will include this in an edit of my question!

I was just notified of your comment with your appreciation for my discussion of Hamilton's stationary action; gratifying indeed. Can I persuade you to contact me directly? I have more to say, but the stackexchange format doesn't lend itself to communicating that. (Contact information for me is available on my website; link to my website is available on my stackexchange profile page.)

@Cleonis Thank you very much for your message. At the moment I am traveling. I will try to get in touch with you next week!

I'm looking forward to getting in touch.
