Why does Lagrangian mechanics state Nature is Extremal, And How?
I was recently learning about the calculus of variations and came across the euler lagrangian formula. $$L_y - \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'} = 0$$
Where $L$ is the Lagrangian
While learning how to use it from a video of Alexander Fufaev, he explained that using an analogy of the displacement-time graph of a ball thrown upwards
He told that the parabola which is formed by the ball is due to the property of the nature and that nature is extremal.
But according to me, i think that the reason the ball follows that exact parabola, is relalated to its position, velocity, and acceleration. This is relevant as
$$L=L(x,y,y')$$
But also the primary reason is that it doesn't have any other force acting on it which doesn't cause it to have any other weird graph and follows the well defined parabola. And Fufaev tells that it's a property  of nature that it will follow the lowest Lagrangian. Which means that if the Langragian of the path of a motion is high, Nature will Somehow, exert a force, to change its lagrangian to a lower state.
But this seems totally counter intuitive as how can nature apply a force itself? Just to change the motion of a body?
I am a ninth grader and all of this is self learnt. So try to give me a more imaginative and visual solution rather than a bunch of math formulae.
Fufaev's video here

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9/2451 and links therein.

You are writing about 'lowest Lagrangian', but that is not correct, in a significant way. For the case of mechanics the variational formulation comes out as follows: there is a Lagrangian $L$, and you set up the integral of that Lagrangian from a starting time coordinate to an end time coordinate. That integral is referred to as the Action. You set up differentiation of the Action with respect to variation of the trial trajectory. The true trajectory corresponds to the point in variation space such that the derivative of the Action (wrt variation) is zero.  Continuing...

... continued About that criterion 'derivative is zero'. The condition that it imposes is that the true trajectory has the following property: the rate of change of kinetic energy matches the rate of change of potential energy. (The derivative of the kinetic energy matches the derivative of the potential energy.) When those two match the derivative of the Action is zero.
